# When is the mollification of an $L^p$ function in $L^p\cap L^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, convolution

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $f_{\varepsilon}=f\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}$ its convolution with the standard mollifier $\varphi_{\varepsilon}$. Then it is well-known that $f_{\varepsilon}\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I would like to find (weak) conditions on $f$ to ensure that $f_{\varepsilon}\in L^p\cap L^{\infty}$ at infinity, e.g. $f_{\varepsilon}\in L^p\cap L^{\infty}(B_R(0)^C)$ for some $R>0$.
I would be grateful for any suggestions!
Since yesterday I know that in general $C^{\infty}\cap L^p(B_R(0)^C)$ is no subspace of $L^q$ for $q>p$ on any $[M,\infty)$.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

> Young's theorem:  Suppose $p,q,r\in[1,\infty]$, If $\frac1r=\frac1p+\frac1q-1$ and $f\in L_p$ and $g\in L_q$ then, $f*g$ exits a.s., $f*g\in L_r$, and
> $$\|f*g\|_r\leq\|f\|_p\|g\|_q$$
> Furthermore, if $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ ($r=\infty$) then $f*g\in C_0$ (continuous vanishing at infinity).

There are many textbooks that present this result, for example Jone, F. Lebeguse integration in Euclidean space, or Folland, G, Real Analysis.

Finally, notice that the *typicall* mollifier is in any $L_p$ space vy virtue of being compactly supported and continuous (in fact smooth).

Comment: Yes, and I would add that in this case, it is just Hölder's inequality

Comment: That and the continuity of translations in $L_p$ and in $\mathcal{C}$.